# Button to change the true / false on a parameter

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to create a button that when we clicked it will change the value of the parameter to true / false.

```
$backurl = "CSP_00.php?prevision=".trim($_REQUEST['prevision']);
```

By default it is true, I did this to pass at false :

```
$switchPrevision = ((bool)trim($_REQUEST['prevision']) and trim($_REQUEST['prevision'])==strtolower("false"));

$foothtmlright.= "<img class=\"tailleIconFooter hover\" src=\"$dos_images/svg/flecheH.svg\" onclick=($switchPrevision)\" />";
```

My problem is my my variable $switchPrevision not my button because when i tried to display my variable with echo I don't have the value false.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$switchPrevision = empty($_REQUEST['prevision']) || trim($_REQUEST['prevision']) == strtolower("false") ? false : true;`

Comment: Im not into PHP but... Does `(bool)trim($_REQUEST['prevision']` assume the datatype is boolean and `trim($_REQUEST['prevision'])` assume it is string? BTW, should't it be `strtolower(trim($_REQUEST['prevision'])) == "false"`?

Comment: Thank your for your reply, I tried your proposition but  it always shows me true and it doesn't change the value.

Comment: _“because when i tried to display my variable with echo I don't have the value false”_ - you can not “output” `false` using echo, that will only result in an empty string. Use `var_dump` to make debug outputs, or echo something else _based on_ whether the value is true or false.

Comment: And `onclick=($switchPrevision)` also doesn’t seem to make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code as 04FS has already pointed out, in summary:

- missing handler function in JS code
- incomprehensibly usage of `strtolower()`
- mixing of boolean and string values for a Bool value

Assuming you have the following JS function in your code:

```js
function switchPrevision(boolPrevision)
{
  window.location = "CSP_00.php?prevision=" + boolPrevision;
}
```

Your PHP code could look like this:

```php
// creates a variable with a string value of the boolean parameter for HTML output
$switchPrevision = isset($_REQUEST['prevision']) && strtolower(trim($_REQUEST['prevision'])) === 'false' ? 'false' : 'true';
// internal variable for easier true/false check
$boolSwitchPrevision = $switchPrevision === 'true';

$foothtmlright.= "<img class=\"tailleIconFooter hover\" src=\"$dos_images/svg/flecheH.svg\" onclick=\"switchPrevision($switchPrevision)\" />";
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, I just removed the quotation marks for the $switchPrevision and it works !

Comment: @ArcanesDev good to hear and thanks for accepting my answer! If you want to read more about variable comparison, check [this article](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) on PHP.net.